# Excel chart: How to reverse the X axis of time series data

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

In Excel 2003, I have a time series from a financial report that goes something like this:

```
         2007 2006 2005
Amount   300  200  100
```

I want to create a graph of the time series that looks something like this (please excuse the ugly ascii graph):

```
300|                .x
   |             ...
200|         .x..
   |      ...
100|    x
   |____________________
  0   2005   2006   2007
```

But intead of getting an upward sloping graph, excel wants to put my time series in reverse (the way it actually appears in the spreadsheet).  Is there any way to make excel display the x axis in reverse of the way it normally does?  I've tried manually reversing the range in the chart dialog (changing a range of B1:D3 to D3:B1), but excel just puts it back.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> 1. Click the axis for the categories, values, or series whose
>      plotting order you want to change.
> 2. On the Format menu, click Selected Axis, and then click the
>      Scale tab.
>
>    *Note  Selected Axis is only available on the Format menu when a
>      data series is selected.*
> 3. To reverse the plotting order, do one of the following:
>
>    - For categories, select the Categories in reverse order check box.
>    - For values, select the Values in reverse order check box.
>    - For series in 3-D charts, select the Series in reverse order
>        check box.

[[Source]](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel/HP051992231033.aspx)

Comment: Beautiful -- thank you so much!  One more thing.  When I checked "Categories in reverse order", the values of the Y axis moved to the right side.  I had to check "Value (Y) axis crosses at maximum catetory" as well to get the Y axis values to appear on the left where they belong.

Answer (score 3):

If you have numerical data, don't make a "Line Chart", make an "XY Chart". This treats the X axis data as numerical values. If you look at more than the Line Chart and XY Chart icons, you will notice that you can apply styles that include markers and lines or lines only to both XY and Line charts.

Line charts are good for categorical X data (non-numerical labels) and for flexible axis scaling for actual dates (year-month-day) but not simple values like years.

Answer (score 1):

SJohnny, similar to you, I had some financial data displayed with dates on the Y axis, and I had the same problem; the line graph I created initially was backward.  However, without using an XY graph, there's a simple way of fixing the chronological order of the data.

1. Select the data you want to graph.
2. Using the graph function (Chart Wizard), select a *line graph*.
3. At step 3 of 4, under "primary axis," select "Time Scale."  This should immediately correct the order for preview before you finsh creating the graph.

Comment: Simple years are not really treated as dates. Or not as you expect. For example, from the example data provided, 2005 is treated as the date 6/27/1905, the 2005th day when you start counting on 1/1/1900. But since 2005 (6/27/1905) < 2006 (6/28/1905) < 2007 (6/29/1905), making this a date axis fits.

Answer (score 1):

For excel 2010/2013, these steps fly: http://blogs.technet.com/b/hub/archive/2010/02/02/excelling-at-excel-how-to-quickly-flip-a-chart.aspx

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.